# Throwing Exception while inserting in cells of Excel file

Tags: java, excel, null, iterator

I have created method to create Excel file and added header from user.

The code is

```
/**
 * Method to add rows to Workbook File. 
 * <br>Here Flag is to check weather adding header row or datarow
 * @param List,Integer
 * @return void*/
public void addrows(List l,int flag) 
{
    int headcount=0,rowcount=1;
    if(flag==0)
    {
        row=sheet.createRow(0);
        row.setHeightInPoints(13);
        Iterator it=l.iterator(); 

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            cell=row.createCell(headcount);
            cell.setCellValue(""+it.next());
            headcount++;
        }
    }

    else if(flag==1)
    {
        Iterator it=l.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            row=sheet.createRow(rowcount);
            row.setHeightInPoints(13);
            rowcount++;
            for(int count=0;count<headcount;count++)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(count);
                cell.setCellValue(""+it.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WHat changes should be made if user dosen't add any data at particular cell and we want to put null at that cell?

Please help me out..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post also the stacktrace

Comment: Can you please give an example of input and the expected output?

Comment: Post full text with imports nd stacktrace

Comment: Sorry but the problem solved.....but thanks for interest......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like the error might come from here :

```
else if(flag==1) {
    Iterator it=l.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        row=sheet.createRow(rowcount);
        row.setHeightInPoints(13);
        rowcount++;
        for(int count=0;count<headcount;count++)
        {
            cell = row.createCell(count);
            cell.setCellValue(""+it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

And should be changed like this :

```
else if(flag==1) {
    Iterator it=l.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        row=sheet.createRow(rowcount);
        row.setHeightInPoints(13);
        rowcount++;
        Object next = it.next();
        for(int count=0;count<headcount;count++)
        {
            cell = row.createCell(count);
            cell.setCellValue(""+next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer, or upvote to confirm this answer solved the problem ;)